# Micron MT25QL512ABB8ESF-0SIT not working after Non Volatile Configuration register setting

Tags: stm32, memory, flash, non-volatile-memory, stm32h750vbt

I'm using the STM32H7 Evaluation board. There is an on-chip QSPI DUAL NOR CHIP [MT25QL512ABB8ESF-0SIT](https://media-www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/nor-flash/serial-nor/mt25q/die-rev-b/mt25q_qlkt_l_512_abb_0.pd). After setting up the Non-volatile configurations Register value to 0x89D6 and power cycle, FLASH is not working as expected.
Now When I read Volatile or Non Volatile configuration register, the values are:

NonVolatile Register Value read : 0x5555

Volatile Register value read : 0x55

Expected Values are:

NonVolatile Register Value read : 0x89D6

Volatile Register value read : 0xFF

As per [This](https://media-www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/technical-note/nor-flash/tn1229_n25q_n25w_reset_configs_ja.pdf?la=en&rev=50bfbf5bea554e06b39902f9b791af2d) document, We can make flash in sync by performing a reset operation.
I have tried Hardware RESET and Software RESET, both are not working.
Also, there is mention of XIP reset and Protocol Reset, but not more info on how to perform these Reset
How to perform XIP Reset? Protocol Reset?

Comment: you might link to that mention...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally issue solved!
As on STM32H7EVAL Board, there is a DUAL QSPI configuration used.
To configure the NonVolatile register of both bank, need to send LSB of Data First then MSB data. i.e. LSB LSB MSB MSB for DUAL BANK configuration.